# Fop Factory Run time exception

Tags: apache-fop

i am trying to execute the following code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;    
//JAXP
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;

//FOP
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the conversion of an XML file to PDF using    * JAXP (XSLT) and FOP (XSL-FO).
 */
public class xml2pd {

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("FOP ExampleXML2PDF\n");
            System.out.println("Preparing...");

            // Setup directories
            File baseDir = new File("e:");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();

            // Setup input and output files
            File xmlfile = new File(baseDir, "ajay.xml");
            File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, "test.xsl");
            File pdffile = new File(outDir, "ResultXML2PDF.pdf");

            System.out.println("Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Transforming...");

            // configure fopFactory as desired
            **strong text**FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            // configure foUserAgent as desired

            // Setup output
            OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
                System.out.println("After MIME_PDF");
                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

            // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

                // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                transformer.transform(src, res);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Success!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(-1);
    }
}
}
```

(this is an example copied from http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/examples/embedding/java/embedding/ExampleXML2PDF.java?view=markup) but i am getting the following runtime error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.<clinit>(FopFactory.java:65)
at ExampleFO2PDF.<init>(ExampleFO2PDF.java:33)
at ExampleFO2PDF.main(ExampleFO2PDF.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

can anybody help me to resolve this...?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need commons-logging package (e.g. `commons-logging-1.0.4.jar`). To do this, just download and put it in your `classpath`.